# Thymeleaf JPA error validation using VO's

Tags: validation, spring-boot, thymeleaf, bean-validation

I'm using thymeleaf+sprinboot for a web application and I wonder how I can control the validation errors when I use Value Objects (VO's).

As you can see, the entity has a constraint (unique) for one attribute:

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id = 0;
    @Column(unique = true)
    String code;
    String name;
    String address;
...
}
```

But the VO is not intended to have it:

```
public class CompanyVO {

    Integer id = 0;
    String code;
    String name;
    String address;
...
}
```

hence, the controller cannot validate if the value is repeated or unique:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String set(@Valid CompanyVO companyVO, BindingResult result, Model model){

    Company company = new Company();

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "company";
    }

    if(companyVO.getId() != 0){
        company = companyRepository.findOne(companyVO.getId());
    }

    mapper.map(companyVO, company);
    companyRepository.save(company);
    return "redirect:/companies";
}
```

How can I show the validation errors on the view when I use VO's?

Answer (score 2):

You only really have one option. To catch the exception from Hibernate/DB about a duplicate value and populate any extra errors in the BindingResult.

Doing a query introduces a race condition. If 2 users try to enter the same value at roughly the same time, both validations can pass (as there's no value in the DB yet) and one of them will fail later as only one transaction will be able to succeed.

When you catch the exception, you can call `BindingResult.addError` with a `FieldError` that contains the field name and error message.